# Does Flink support keyed watermarks? If not, is there any plan of implementing it in future versions? What are my alternatives?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We collect driving data from thousands of users, each vehicle is associated with a IMEI (unique code).  The device installed in these vehicles emits GPS points in 5 second intervals. My requirement is to assemble all the GPS points that belong to a single trip and construct a Trip object, for a given IMEI.

I am using event time and Session windows to detect the end of a trip (10 minutes of non reception of GPS coordinates), and another 15 minutes of allowed lateness to wait for late events. The watermark then gets advanced to the latest received event time. Let's say this is for IMEI=100. Now, if I receive data for IMEI's 1 through 99 that have event time behind this watermark, all that data will be deemed late and won't be processed.

In other words, if one vehicle's data advances the watermark, then the data from all other vehicles will be considered late, because Watermarks are global.

Given my problem, is there a way I can implement different watermarks for different keys? If not directly possible, is there some way I can simulate it to suit my application?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find the solution? We have the very similar problem and the lack of keyed watermarks made us move to another streaming platform..

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem possible with Flink, at least for now.

Comment: Hello @HarshithBolar, we implemented Keyed Watermarks in Apache Flink. Let's discuss.

Answer (score 3):

Flink does not support per-key watermarks, at least not yet.

On the other hand, there is support for per-partition watermarks for the Kafka consumer. So if you are using Kafka and can afford a partition for each vehicle, that could be a solution.

Otherwise you might consider building up the sessions yourself by using Flink's low-level APIs, rather than relying on session windows. But without being able to use watermarks to trigger event-time timers, that doesn't sound straightforward.